# Как на веб-странице сделать слитые маркеры у списка

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как получить на html/js/css слитые маркеры у списка (пример на изображении):

```
<ul>

    <li>Элемент 1</li>
    <li>элемент 2</li>
    <li>элемент 3</li>
    <li>элемент 4</li>
    <li><ul><li>подэлемент 1</li></ul></li>

</ul>
```

[image: Изображение]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так, потом если что подправить, но идея должна быть понятна.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
}
ul li::before, ul li::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -33px;
  top: 7px;
  background-color: red;
}
ul li::before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
}
ul li::after {
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
}
ul li:last-child::after {
  content: none;
}
ul ol {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
ul ol::before, ul ol::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: -10px;
  background-color: red;
}
ul ol::before {
  width: 2px;
  height: 50%;
}
ul ol::after {
  top: 7px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3
  <ol>
    <li>Под 1</li>
    <li>Под 2</li>
  </ol>
  </li>
  
</ul>
```